# How to Position Image and Icons at Bottom of Video Using CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I'd like to add image and icons to my video, but I don't know how to  do that using CSS.

I want the image that serve as profile picture and my icons to be like these icons in the picture down below:

[image: this:]

I'm trying to use `position: absolute`, `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` and use `bottom: 100%`, but the method did not work. This is what I have tried, but feel like I can't make it to work:

This template contains Bootstrap-5 classes and Video.js with google icons.

```css
.img_wrapper.a img {
        position: absolute;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        bottom: 100%;
    }
    
 .thumb{
        width: 30px;
        height: auto;
    }
```

```html
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.4/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/8.0.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">

            <div class="col-md-2">
                
                <div class="row">
                    <video id="my-video"
                            class="video-js text-center"
                            controls
                            preload="auto"
                            height="400px"
                            data-setup="{}"
                            poster="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/confident-black-business-man-stylish-suit-standing-folded-arms-rooftop-n-office-block-looking-camera-69650703.jpg"
                            muted>
                        <source src="" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>

                    <div class="img_wrapper">
                        <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="{{ video.get_user_public_url }}">
                            <p><img class="rounded-circle thumb" src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/confident-black-business-man-stylish-suit-standing-folded-arms-rooftop-n-office-block-looking-camera-69650703.jpg" alt="">
                                <b>Bamagujen Bahaushe</b>
                            </p>
                        </a>
                    </div>  
                    
                    <div class="video-icons">
                        <a href="">
                            <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                                fingerprint
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="{% url 'Play-Video' video.slug %}">
                            <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                                comment
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="{% url 'Complain-Video' video.pk %}">
                            <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                                flag
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>  
            
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="content-right">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur
                        adipisicing elit. Qui, minus, optio atque nostrum 
                    repellendus delectus eos non veritatis, 
                    illum soluta quas id aliquid facilis molestiae 
                    facere nam neque? Fugiat, repellendus.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-link-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification but your usage is also inconsistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do the following:

- Wrap text and icons with a `row` to place text to the left and icons to the right.
- Add Bootstrap classes `position-absolute bottom-0` to the `row` and `position-relative` to the parent(!) `row` to place text and icons inside the video at the bottom.
- Add Bootstrap classes `d-flex flex-column` to the right column to stack icons vertically.
- Add Bootstrap classes `d-flex align-items-end` to the `row` to push text down to the bottom of the `row` because the right column with icons is taller than the left column with text.
- Add Bootstrap class `mb-3` to the `row` to add some `margin-bottom` for better UX.
- Add Bootstrap class `mx-auto` to the `row` to center it horizontally.
- Add the following CSS to make your `<img>` rounded on every screen size (you can also replace `px` with `vw` if you like): `.rounded-circle { width: 25px; height: 25px; }`.
- Add Bootstrap class `pe-1` (i.e., `padding-right`) to the left `col` and `ps-1` (i.e., `padding-left`) to the right `col` to make a smaller space between the image and "Bamagujen Bahaushe" text.

See the snippet below.

```css
.img_wrapper.a img {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  bottom: 100%;
}

.thumb {
  width: 30px;
  height: auto;
}


/* Added */
.rounded-circle {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.4/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/8.0.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="row position-relative">
        <video id="my-video" class="video-js text-center" controls preload="auto" height="400px" data-setup="{}" poster="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/confident-black-business-man-stylish-suit-standing-folded-arms-rooftop-n-office-block-looking-camera-69650703.jpg"
          muted>
          <source src="" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div class="row position-absolute bottom-0 d-flex align-items-end mb-3 mx-auto">
          <div class="col-md-10 col img_wrapper">
            <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="{{ video.get_user_public_url }}">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-auto pe-1">
                  <img class="rounded-circle thumb" src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/confident-black-business-man-stylish-suit-standing-folded-arms-rooftop-n-office-block-looking-camera-69650703.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col ps-1">
                  <b>Bamagujen Bahaushe</b>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-auto video-icons d-flex flex-column">
            <a href="">
              <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                fingerprint
              </span>
            </a>
            <a href="{% url 'Play-Video' video.slug %}">
              <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                comment
              </span>
            </a>
            <a href="{% url 'Complain-Video' video.pk %}">
              <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                flag
              </span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="content-right">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui, minus, optio atque nostrum repellendus delectus eos non veritatis, illum soluta quas id aliquid facilis molestiae facere nam neque? Fugiat, repellendus.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong but there are a couple of things to note here.

Firstly I think `img_wrapper.a img` should be `img_wrapper a img`. The former is looking for the `img_wrapper` class that also has a class of `a` because you are concatenating it with a period. The latter looks for the `img_wrapper` with an anchor as a child node, with an image as a child node of the anchor.

Secondly, ensure that the `img_wrapper` has a relative position.

And then I removed the translate css, and just passed in bottom and left attributes. I think this should do what you want, but you might have to tweak the px values for left and bottom. The other thing to note is you might have an issue with responsiveness, but that can be tackled separately. And it might not be an issue at all actually, but it depends.

**EDIT**

I have made two jsfiddles. Both contain a wrapper which is positioned absolutely but we pass in a px value for `right`. In the first example I am using a list which naturally reads top to bottom for each list item, then just added a little styling to remove the default bullet items, and margins, padding.

The second is the same but using a flex layout to control the flow of content inside the wrapper.

The parts to note are:

HTML1:

```
<div class="img_wrapper_right">
   <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS1:

```
.img_wrapper_right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #fc0;
}

.img_wrapper_right ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

HTML2:

```
<div class="img_wrapper_right">
   <p>Item 1</p>
   <p>Item 2</p>
   <p>Item 4</p>
   <p>Item 5 much longer item</p>
</div>
```

CSS2:

```
.img_wrapper_right {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    right: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #fc0;
}

.img_wrapper_right p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

If it was me I would try and abstract this code. Make multiple class names and pass attributes to them as needed. Then the main class name can be inherited. Something like

```
.absolute-wrapper { position: absolute; }
.absolute-wrapper .left { left: 10px; }
.absolute-wrapper .right { right: 20px; }
```

etc.

JSFIDDLE1: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/06vb932e/

JSFIDDLE2: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/7g89bthv/

**EDIT 2**

Just reread your question about the `video-icons` for this to work you have to use relative positioning on the nearest common parent. In your case it is the `row` just above, as this contains both the `img_wrapper` and the `video-icons` as direct children. Add a classname to the `row`, and position it relatively, then you can position both the `img_wrapper` and the `video-icons` inside this container using absolute positioning.

```css
.img_wrapper {
     position: relative;
 }

.img_wrapper a img {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 50px;
        left: 20px;
    }
    
 .thumb{
        width: 30px;
        height: auto;
    }
```

```html
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.4/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/8.0.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">

            <div class="col-md-2">
                
                <div class="row">
                    <video id="my-video"
                            class="video-js text-center"
                            controls
                            preload="auto"
                            height="400px"
                            data-setup="{}"
                            poster="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/confident-black-business-man-stylish-suit-standing-folded-arms-rooftop-n-office-block-looking-camera-69650703.jpg"
                            muted>
                        <source src="" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>

                    <div class="img_wrapper">
                        <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="{{ video.get_user_public_url }}">
                            <p><img class="rounded-circle thumb" src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/confident-black-business-man-stylish-suit-standing-folded-arms-rooftop-n-office-block-looking-camera-69650703.jpg" alt="">
                                <b>Bamagujen Bahaushe</b>
                            </p>
                        </a>
                    </div>  
                    
                    <div class="video-icons">
                        <a href="">
                            <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                                fingerprint
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="{% url 'Play-Video' video.slug %}">
                            <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                                comment
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="{% url 'Complain-Video' video.pk %}">
                            <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                                flag
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>  
            
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="content-right">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur
                        adipisicing elit. Qui, minus, optio atque nostrum 
                    repellendus delectus eos non veritatis, 
                    illum soluta quas id aliquid facilis molestiae 
                    facere nam neque? Fugiat, repellendus.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            
        </div>
    </div>  
    <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/8.0.4/video.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey! The way I would do it is to create wrappers that you want placed absolutely, so if you want something bottom left that reads left to right create some container (like left-wrapper) and move all the stuff you want to be placed there inside that) that is don't try and place each individual item absolutely. Similarly for the right wrapper, create a container then position that with right 10px or whatever, then fill that with your content, you can use a list, or flex to ensure the content fills like a column. Hope that is enough info if not update your question and users can chip in

Comment: I can make an example if you need it but it might be better if you try and then update the question if you still get stuck.